# Python methods from RobotFramework Variables section

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a python file named getProperty.py, in that I have only one method!

```
import configparser

def desiredCapability(platform, key):
    conf= configparser.RawConfigParser()
    if platform.lower() == "android":
      conf.read("somepath")
    elif platform.lower() == "ios":
      conf.read("some path")
    else:
      return None
    strr=conf.get( "main",key)
    return strr
```

I have a robot file where I have ***variables*** section

```
***Settings***
 Library   getProperty.py

***Variables***
 ${deviceName}    #Here i want to call the method
```

When i'm trying to call the method in that variables section, it is taking as string! I can call the method inside the ***Test cases*** section with no trouble! But I want it in ***variables*** section!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call keywords in the `Variables` table. From the [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-table):

> The most common source for variables are Variable tables in test case files and resource files. Variable tables are convenient, because they allow creating variables in the same place as the rest of the test data, and the needed syntax is very simple. **Their main disadvantages are that values are always strings and they cannot be created dynamically.** If either of these is a problem, variable files can be used instead.

Comment: Yes sir, I found a solution for this one! 
What I did is, I edited that getProperty.py file, I created all the variables in that file,
ex-:
`    deviceName=desiredCapability("android","deviceName")   `

and in robot settings section i importing this python file as variables and i used them directly!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to be able to load variables with specific content given a certain variable element. With your chosen approach this isn't possible, as explained by @Bryan Oakley.

That said, it is possible to have variable data sets and most of us use them on a daily basis. Often the use-case is to have a single set of tests that can be run against multiple environments. Each environment having a different URL, Credentials and other properties.

One approach is to load a set of variables from the command line using a variable file. The [Documentation on Variable files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id561) gives several approaches:

1. Defining Python variables in a Python file and referring to it.
2. Defining variables in a YAML variable file.
3. Defining variables in a Python Class or Python function.

The first two contain fixed variables and the last one can take an argument and return values depending the input. In the below example we use a Python Function to give back the `${name}` variable with a certain value given a particular input.

**variable_file.py**

```
def get_variables(platform=None, key=None):

    if platform.lower() == "android":
        variables = {'name' : 'android'}

    elif platform.lower() == "ios":
        variables = {'name' : 'ios'}

    else:
        variables = {'name' : 'No Device'}    

    return variables
```

**variable_file.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    ${EXECDIR}/variable_file.py    ios

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    Log To Console     ${name}
```

In this example the variable file is referenced like `Variables    ${EXECDIR}/variable_file.py    ios` with the argument `ios`. This then results in the `${name}` variable holding the value `ios`.